# Can't restart nginx in django deployment app

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps) for deployment a django app in my droplet, but in the step four, when said:

> Now restart NGINX with the command below and you should be set:

I have to run the follow command:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

but I got this error:

> Failed to restart ngnix.service: Unit ngnix.service not found.

I know that I need the file nginx.service but I didn't find a question about this...

How can I fix it?

Comment: @daniherrera I have installed `nginx`

Comment: Did you tried t`sudo systemctl restart nginx`?

Comment: The error indicates that you have a typo: `ngnix` should be `nginx` which is why it cannot be found.

Comment: @solarissmoke is not the same?

Comment: No, it's not the same...